# Как установить firebase c++ в определенный каталог?

Tags: c++, firebase, cmake

скачиваю с github firebase-sdk.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DDESKTOP=ON -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DFIREBASE_CPP_BUILD_TESTS=OFF -DINSTALL_PREFIX=~/code/c++/firebase ..
```

он собирается. а потом когда пишу.

```
make install
[  1%] Built target zlibstatic
[  3%] Built target uv_a
[  5%] Built target libuWS
[  5%] Built target absl_log_severity
[  5%] Built target absl_raw_logging_internal
[  5%] Built target absl_bad_optional_access
[  5%] Built target absl_spinlock_wait
[  6%] Built target absl_dynamic_annotations
[  6%] Built target absl_throw_delegate
[  6%] Built target absl_base
[  6%] Built target absl_int128
[  6%] Built target absl_strings_internal
[  8%] Built target absl_strings
[ 10%] Built target absl_time_zone
[ 10%] Built target absl_civil_time
[ 10%] Built target absl_time
[ 11%] Built target firestore_util
[ 11%] Built target upb
[ 16%] Built target libprotobuf
[ 20%] Built target c-ares
[ 20%] Built target address_sorting
[ 20%] Built target absl_str_format_internal
[ 21%] Built target gpr
[ 48%] Built target grpc
[ 51%] Built target grpc++
[ 55%] Built target leveldb
[ 55%] Built target protobuf-nanopb-static
[ 60%] Built target libprotoc
[ 60%] Built target protoc
[ 60%] Built target firestore_nanopb
[ 61%] Built target firestore_protos_nanopb
[ 70%] Built target firestore_core
[ 70%] Built target flatbuffers
[ 71%] Built target flatc
[ 73%] Built target firebase_app
[ 83%] Built target libcurl
[ 83%] Built target firebase_rest_lib
[ 83%] Built target firebase_admob
[ 85%] Built target firebase_analytics
[ 88%] Built target firebase_auth
[ 93%] Built target firebase_database
[ 93%] Built target firebase_dynamic_links
[ 93%] Built target absl_bad_variant_access
[ 95%] Built target firebase_firestore
[ 96%] Built target firebase_functions
[ 96%] Built target firebase_installations
[ 96%] Built target firebase_messaging
[ 98%] Built target firebase_remote_config
[100%] Built target firebase_storage
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужная переменная называется CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX, а не INSTALL_PREFIX. При этом лучше использовать абсолютный путь без ~/ .

Стандартная последовательность сборки и установки:

```
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/my_app/" ..
 cmake --build . --config=Release -- -j12
 cmake --build . --config=Release --target=install
```